# streaming gdb mi parser

Tags: parsing, gdb, saxparser

I wrote a simple gdb/mi parser that could parse gdb/mi values into a tree. But now I want to build a streaming parser so that I can throw part of the gdb/mi output to the parser, or something like a sax-parser.

I only know how to implement a recursive parser to parse values, but not the whole mi output. Besides, I don't know how to make the parser pause and continue on demand.

Could anyone give me some idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few general notes.

First, the MI grammar in the manual is wrong in some places.  Due to backward compatibility, nobody has fixed the code.  Due to I don't know what... laziness or lack of joy maybe, nobody has fixed the manual either.  The details are either in closed (sigh) bugs in bugzilla or in the mailing list archives.

Second, the approach would be to treat each line of output from gdb as the text to be parsed.

Third, there are several other existing MI parsers already.  You may prefer to start with an existing one.

Fourth, or you might want to just write code in Python inside of gdb and avoid the whole parsing mess.  It's not totally clear that Python covers all the functionality exposed by MI, but it's probably pretty close.